# Setting tintColor for Apple Watch complication

Tags: swift, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I am trying to set the header text color for a Modular Large complication.

I have already customized the watch face to use Multicolor.

However, when I build and run this code, the header text color is still white (which is the default).

Why isn't the color updating?

```
private func templateForClassModularLarge(className: Schedule) -> CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody {
    let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
    let headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "My Schedule", shortText: "Schedule")
    headerTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor(red: 101, green: 153, blue: 255, alpha: 1)
    template.headerTextProvider = headerTextProvider

    template.body1TextProvider = CLKTimeIntervalTextProvider(startDate: className.start, endDate: className.end)
    template.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: className.description, shortText: className.shortDescription)

    return template
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIColor` parameter types are `CGFloat`, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

Because your RGB parameters are greater than 1, the color ends up being white, which would be:

```
UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

To fix this issue, simply change your tintColor to

```
headerTextProvider.tintColor = UIColor(red: 101/255, green: 153/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
```